# Trouble to read an excel file with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to read an excel file with pandas (+50000 rows), and it gives me the same error in all cases.
the code:

```
strfile='C:\\Users\\...\\excel_files\\excelfile_01.xls'
```

Try 01:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(strfile, low_memory=False)
```

Try 02:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(strfile, encoding='utf-16-le',low_memory=False)
```

Try 03:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(strfile, encoding='sys.getfilesystemencoding()',low_memory=False)
```

Try 04:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(strfile, encoding='latin-1',low_memory=False)
```

The error in all cases:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 146-147: unexpected end of data
```

Any help/tip will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `encoding='latin-1'`?

Comment: @coldspeed, thanks, already tested, but with the same error as result

Comment: As a test, have you tried saving as CSV and using `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: @jpp I have tested with 1 file (I have a 400+ excel files I need to read) but gives me the following error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Try saving your legacy `.xls` file in the modern `.xlsx` format and send it to `pd.read_excel()`

Comment: Already solved by creating an excel macro to batch open all files and save them as .xlsx as @jeschwar suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my previous comment as an answer:

Try saving your legacy `.xls` file in the modern `.xlsx` format and send it to `pd.read_excel()`